# EOF occurred in violation of protocol with Python ftplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

I'm working on an implicit TLS connection program with Python ftplib. I tried the solution provided in question [python-ftp-implicit-tls-connection-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164470/python-ftp-implicit-tls-connection-issue)(including Rg Glpj's and Juan Moreno's answers) to make the connection. But when I call `retrline` or `retrbinary` after logging into the ftp server like this(`FTP_ITLS` is the subclass of `FTP_TLS`):

```
58 server = FTP_ITLS()
59 server.connect(host="x.x.x.x", port=990)
60 server.login(user="user", passwd="******")
61 server.prot_p()
62
63 server.cwd("doc")
64 print(server.retrlines('LIST'))
65 # server.retrbinary('RETR contents.7z', open('contents.7z', 'wb').write)
66 server.quit()
```

I got an EOF error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coding/test/itls.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(server.retrlines('LIST'))
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 735, in retrlines
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 713, in ntransfercmd
    server_hostname=self.host)
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

As it seems ftplib uses `PROTOCOL_SSLv23` as the default protocol in Python 2.7, I tried
PROTOCOL_TLSv1, PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1 and PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, but none of them worked. And I also tried overriding `ntransfercmd` and `auth`, or setting `ctx = ssl._create_stdlib_context(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)` as Steffen Ullrich said in question [connect-to-ftp-tls-1-2-server-with-ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276529/connect-to-ftp-tls-1-2-server-with-ftplib), but the error never disappeared. What can I do then? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this trying to connect to a FileZilla FTP server.  FileZilla has a setting in the *"FTP over TLS settings"* called *"Require TLS session resumption on data connection when using PROT P"*.  Disabling this option fixed this problem.

If you don't have control over the server, check out [FTPS with Python ftplib - Session reuse required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659154/ftpes-session-reuse-required) which goes over how to enable session reuse.  This seems to require Python 3.6+, however.

Comment: This answer points to the correct solution in the *second paragraph*. – Do not follow the first advice. The "session resumption" requirement is a security feature. You do not want to turn it off.